# Cannot get data from Queue

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

I'm trying to use a joinable queue and i didn't get anything when join()
is called on queue

```
from multiprocessing import JoinableQueue,Pool

q = JoinableQueue()

def pat(i):
    q.put("hello"+str(i))
    q.join()
    print(q.get())

with Pool(5) as  p:
    (p.map_async(pat,range(5))).get()

res = q.get()
print(res+"main")
q.task_done()
```

I get data from queue only after process exits

Can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 0):

`.run()` directly runs the process target function in the main process. Use `.start()` to fork a new process.

Comment: Actually the problem is i get data put in queue after process exits

Comment: If you put `print('stuff')` after `Process(target=pat).run()` you will not see `stuff` in the output because it doesn't get past the run because you're not starting a new process.

Comment: Okay thanks. It worked but i actually thought it could work with pool too.Actually this is code and get data after process exits

Comment: The `get` requires the `pat` functions to run to completion before you can move past the `with` block, which obviously can't happen. If you remove it the `with` statement closes the pool before it can do its work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try with custom implementation